# How to enable logging in mean stack openshift?

Tags: logging, openshift, mean-stack

I'm creating my first application using MEAN stack and openshift. I just generated code with yeoman and so far it is running correctly when I'm running on my own machine (changed facebook application URL to localhost:9000). But, when I push the code to openshift it just shows an "Internal Server Error" whenever I connect to facebook. So, I would like to enable logging for my application. When I'm running on my machine, it is possible to see information regarding all the links accessed and response time. How do I enable logging in my application and save it in openshift log.

Answer (score 0):

You should be getting log output in OpenShift's default log directory already. Have you tried using `rhc tail`?

```
$ rhc tail -a MyApp
```

See also:

- [Using Log files on OpenShift](https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-log-files.html)
- [Node.js Development Mode](http://docs.openshift.org/origin-m4/oo_cartridge_guide.html#development-mode)
- [Local Node.js Development + Testing](http://docs.openshift.org/origin-m4/oo_cartridge_guide.html#local-development-testing)